# To display queries in MySQL executed by a particular user

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, devops

I have MySQL user called as **test**,

> show processlist

It shows all queries running on MySQL host but I don't want all queries. 
Instead, I want only queries which 'test' user is running or has executed in the past.

Can someone help me how can I do that?

Comment: Why did you give the user test SUPER privilege? MySQL user's with SUPER see all processes in the `SHOW PROCESSLIST`

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL 5.1.7 or newer, you can use the PROCESSLIST table in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. So you can query it with ordinary SELECT queries and apply filtering conditions in a WHERE clause.

Note: This feature is not implemented in MySQL 5.0 and prior.